# Music played via Amazon Music app cannot be controlled by Pebble Music app

Tags: bluetooth, pebble

Many a times I use my Pebble time watch to control the music played on my smartphone. Pebble connects to Smartphone via Bluetooth. I use Pebble Music app to control the music played on my device. I can perfectly control(pause/next/previous song) Spotify, Google Ply Music and default music apps. Recently amazon launched Music streaming in India and I have been trying for last two weeks to control the music via Pebble music app with no luck.

I am on Android version 7.1.1, LG Skin UI, using Pebble Time with latest firmware, the official Pebble app and Amazon Music app version 7.5.4

Anyone facing similar issue? 
What could be possible hack/solution to this issue?

Comment: What Pebble app are you using on your Android device?The "official" (no longer maintained) one, or Gadgetbridge (FOSS, available via F-Droid)?

Comment: I am using the official Pebble app.

Comment: I've integrated that with your question. Might be worth to try [Gadgetbridge](https://f-droid.org/packages/nodomain.freeyourgadget.gadgetbridge/) (which is well maintained, I'm using it myself) and see if it works with that.

Comment: Ok. Will give it a try.